# Modeling a temperature recording device in Rails

Tags: beginner, ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

The app will allow users to login and upload a CSV file that contains temperature data from a device. This data will be stored and the user can view all these downloads and select one from a list to view using Highcharts.

Where I am getting hung up is with the temperature recorder device model. Each device has a unit serial number that the user would enter and contains roughly 200 time/temp data points. There could be 150-200 of these files uploaded each day. Given that potential volume of downloads a table for one company's temp recorders could grow by 30000 rows each day. I wasn't sure if in the long run this would be a black eye for performance.

The following schema works in my application. The user is able to upload and view the data I just don't think it is practical with a larger volume of CSV files being uploaded.

I'm relatively new to Rails and would like your thoughts on how to best model data for my practice app.

```
create_table "temp_data", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "point"
    t.datetime "date"
    t.float    "temp"
    t.string   "alarm"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "serial"
  end
```

I'm not sure if I should have two tables with serial_numbers that has_many :data_points and data_points that belongs_to :serial_numbers.

Comment: I can't be sure what every element in your table is (e.g. what is _alarm_?), but it seems to me like you should be able to compact all the temperature data. Surely you don't need to store `created_at`, `updated_at` and `serial` for all 200 rows? Only once per file would seem sufficient to me. Perhaps you can even combine multiple files. That would depend on what you want with the data though.